# Nx generate get 'Collection "@nrwl/storybook" cannot be resolved.' error

Tags: storybook, nrwl-nx, angular-storybook

I'm trying to add storybook to exist angular lib in my workspace:

`ng generate @nrwl/angular:storybook-configuration <lib-name>`

But get a "Collection "@nrwl/storybook" cannot be resolved." error.

Same error when I'm trying to do it with the Nx's VSCode plugin.

Nx v 10.4.4.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is correct.

Try run `npm i @nrwl/storybook` or `yarn add @nrwl/storybook` first and retry.